# how edit an existing image (auto_orient!) with CarrierWave::RMagick?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, rmagick

I have :

```
class Painting < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
  ...
end
```

and

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::RMagick
  storage :file
  process :fix_exif_rotation


  def fix_exif_rotation
    manipulate! do |img|
      img.auto_orient!
      img = yield(img) if block_given?
      img
    end
  end

end
```

this works fine on new uploading image, but I want a script to execute `auto_orient!` on each image already existing, because I just add fix_exif_rotation code and old image have orientation problem....

I try :

```
Painting.first.image.fix_exif_rotation
```

> CarrierWave::ProcessingError (Failed to manipulate with rmagick, maybe it is not an image?)

```
Painting.first.image.auto_orient!
```

> NoMethodError (undefined method `auto_orient!' for #)

so what good method ?

Answer (score 0):

Try with recreate_versions! method https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#recreating-versions

```
Painting.first.image.recreate_versions!
```

I'm not sure if it applies only for extra versions or also the original.